# AWS Gateway Cognitoオーソライザーのテストが401エラーになる

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

Gatewayのオーソライザーを使ってAPIの認証をしようとしているのですが、
オーソライザーのテスト段階で401エラーになってしまいます。
解決法はないでしょうか？
以下詳細です。

【Cognito設定】

・ユーザー
　　　認証済みユーザーを追加ずみ
　　　(SRP_AUTHは成功していることからおそらく正しい)
　・グループ
　　　特に設定なし
　・サインインエクスペリエンス
　　　サインインオプション：ユーザー名
　　　ユーザー名の要件：ユーザー名では大文字と小文字が区別されません
　　　フェデレーテッドアイデンティティプロバイダーのサインイン：なし
　　　パスワードポリシー：デフォルト
　　　多要素認証：なし
　　　ユーザーアカウントの復旧：なし
　　　デバイスを追跡：なし
　・サインアップオプション
　　　Cognito が検証と確認のためにメッセージを自動的に送信することを許可：はい
　　　検証する属性：E メールのメッセージを送信、E メールアドレスを検証
　　　未完了の更新があるときに元の属性値をアクティブに保つ：有効
　　　未完了の更新があるときのアクティブな属性値：E メールアドレス
　　　必須の属性：なし
　　　カスタム属性：なし
　　　セルフサービスのサインアップ：無効
　・メッセージング
　　　すべてデフォルト
　・アプリケーションの統合
　　　アプリクライアントと分析
　　　　認証フロー
ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
　
【オーソライザー】
　　オーソライザーのタイプ：Cognito
ユーザープール：対象のユーザープール
　　トークンのソース：Authorization
トークンの検証：なし

【トークン取得処理】
　・この処理で取得したトークンをオーソライザーのテストに使用(lambda:python3.10)

username = event['queryStringParameters']['username']
password = event['queryStringParameters']['password']

```
   # Cognitoのユーザープール情報
   user_pool_id = os.environ.get("user_pool_id")
   client_id = os.environ.get("client_id")

   # Cognitoへの認証を試行
   try:
      cognito = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
      response = cognito.initiate_auth(
          AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',  # 認証フローのタイプ
          AuthParameters={
              'USERNAME': username,  # ユーザー名
              'PASSWORD': password  # パスワード
          },
          ClientId=client_id
      )
      # 認証成功時の処理
      return {
         'statusCode': 200,
         'body': json.dumps({'result': 200, 'token': response.get('AuthenticationResult')})
     }
```

【備考】
　　トークンの取得自体は成功しており、トークンをそのままオーソライザーの値のところに入れている。
　　空白が入っていないかやAuthorization等の綴りが間違っていないことはチェック済み。

Answer (score 2):

AccessTokenとIdTokenを勘違いしていました。IdTokenに変更したところうまくいきました。